# XBOX 360 SLIM RGH Won't power on, only green dot

Tags: technical-issues, xbox-360

I have this strange problem. I have an Xbox 360 slim rgh and everything was working great. A few days ago, I bought a not-working Kinect, I repaired it, and when connected it to my Xbox, I accidentally shorted the Kinect's 12V and ground wires, on the Xbox's AUX connector. The Xbox shut down so I restarted the power supply. The Xbox started, fan is working, green dot is on, Coolrunner red light is on, green LED is blinking in 5 seconds rate. I measured the voltage on kinect connector, 12V and 5V are present.

I tried replacing the HDMI cable, connecting it to another monitor, using AV cable, but nothing helps.

I am out of ideas, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: I know this is going to sound wild, but have you turned on the device that the Xbox is connected to, and changed it to the proper source? The 360 Slim won't power on fully until it sees an active signal from the TV, IIRC.

Comment: yes, I done everything as usual.

Comment: You might have shorted out across the GFX card. I would suggest testing around the power inputs of the unit and the output signals.